# preg issue with PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following piece of PHP code:

```
$string = "Ouch!; Funny, these photos were taken with my own phone... … ";
echo preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9:\/.,;]", '', $string);
```

As far as I can tell, this removes everything that is not Alphanumeric as well as the characters: : . , /

When I run it, I get:

```
Ouch!; Funny, these photos were taken with my own phone... â€¦
```

Instead of what I was expecting:

```
Ouch!; Funny, these photos were taken with my own phone...
```

These special characters are still making it in, even though I am excluding them. Any ideas?

## Answer:

Summarized from the answers and comments below - this will eliminate special characters, but allows .',;?/\: and insures that we don't end up with multiple blanks:

```
preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:\/.,;!#@'?!\s+!]/",' ', $string)
```

Comment: You forgot to add delimiters (the `[]` are seen as delimiters now instead, making it not a character class), and you might want to add the `/u` in there when using utf-8 (multi-byte character sets means a single byte from a sequence can accidentally match otherwise): `preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:\/.,;]/u",`

Answer (score 1):

PHP regular expressions, including `preg_replace`, expect delimiters around the regular expression.

```
$string = "Ouch!; Funny, these photos were taken with my own phone... … ";
echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:\/.,;]/u", ' ', $string);
```

Note the `/` on either side of your expression. You'll also probably want the `utf-8` modifier `u` (thx @jon).

Now in this case, you're actually going to end up with:

```
Ouch;Funny,thesephotosweretakenwithmyownphone...
```

This isn't what you wrote out however; in order to do that, you'll need a bit more complex code. You could simply replace with `' '` (space) but you might end up with a bunch of unwanted whitespace.

Comment: While this is true, the real problem here is that `preg_replace` needs to be put into UTF-8 mode otherwise characters outside of ASCII such as the `…` are going to get clobbered.

Comment: I copied the code and output before I modified the replacement from '' to ' ' to make sure that whatever preg_replace removes is replaced with spaces.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper that works, except if you have multiple characters you'll end up with a slew of whitespaces.

Comment: PS: thanks for the UTF8 reminder. In my case though, the application does not need (and cannot handle) anything other than ASCII. Multiple spaces can be handled by running the function through another filter to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$string = "Ouch!; Funny, these photos were taken with my own phone... … ";
echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9:\/\.,; ]/", '', $string);
```

http://3v4l.org/ne7Qu